# How to return back a data from a function and use in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I was trying to read and file by using a function and need to print that data from main code. Below shown is my code.

```
getJsonData().then(function (jsonData) {
console.log(jsonData)
})

function getJsonData(){
  var fs = require('fs');
  var XLSX = require('xlsx');
  let contents = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
  let jsonData = JSON.parse(contents);
  return jsonData ;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of All, that function isn't a promise, so you can't use `.then`. Here is how you would turn this code into a promise:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var XLSX = require('xlsx');

    function getJsonData(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let contents = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
        if(contents == "undefined") {
          reject("File contains no contents");
        } else {
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(contents);
            resolve(jsonData);
        }
      })  


}
```

You would then use the function like you did in the question:

```
getJsonData().then(function (jsonData) {
  console.log(jsonData)
})
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, could you clarify pls?

Answer (score 0):

`readFileSync` doesn't return a promise, so you can't use `.then()` after `getJsonData()`, as `getJsonData()` doesn't return a promise.

You can simply use:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const results = getJsonData();
console.log(results);

function getJsonData() {
  const contents = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
  return JSON.parse(contents);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I have  tried this, but when I start to work with the json that is been returned due to asynchronous behavior of node, since jsn read before json returns met error.. so I tried to use then

Comment: `readFileSync` is asnychronous, it will block execution until the content is read